# How to retrieve specific information from a certain website?

Tags: java, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am developing a java web application and I want to know how to take a certain field (table and/or output-text) value from a certain website. Assuming that this component has always the same ID does anyone know how can I retrieve this information?
I don't know if anyone has ever faced this issue but if anyone has any idea please share.
Thank you.

Comment: use `jsoup` for this http://jsoup.org/

Comment: `I am developing a java web application` - why did you tag this [php] then?

Comment: You could try webharvest too

Comment: because website can be even php, however I tagged it just to get general information. I didn't know nothing about this before asking :)

Comment: @AlbanoVito When you see a website in your browser, there is no more php present, because you only get the finished markup (let's ignore Java script for now)

Comment: OK my bad, I am sorry

Comment: *"I don't know if anyone has ever faced this issue.."*  People trying to rip off content published by others?  That *is* new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:
 1.) Retrieve the pages markup by reading it through an HTTPConnection to the URL in your application
 2.) Parse the Markup using a framework like jsoup and retrieve the value you need.

More specifically, here is some example code for jsoup:

```
HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
String htmlcode = "";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = http.execute(request);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(response != null){
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = "";
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
        htmlcode += line; 
    }
}
// at this point we have the pages markup
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlcode);
Elements lis = doc.getElementsByTag("li"); // get all entries in lists
for(Element el : lis){
    String val = el.text().trim();
    // do something for each list entry
}
```

Comment: What clumsy. You can also just do `Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get()` to get the document by URL without the need for the whole HttpClient boilerplate (which has in your particular example by the way character encoding problems, you're relying on platform default encoding).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. That was just typed together without completely studying the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about web scraping, check this library for php:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thats php library, this question is no longer tagged [php]

Comment: @DevZer0 Ah, yeah he removed the tag now.